# what is the mapping of horizontal lines and vertical lines under $w(z)=sin(z)$ in general?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

For the mapping of horizontal lines ($z=x+iy_0$ for fixed $y_0$) and vertical lines ($z=x_0+iy$ for fixed $x_0$) under $w(z) = \sin(z)$, are there any general formulas?

What I mean is, is there a general formula like "$z=x_0+iy$ is mapped to a hyperbola with the vertex (something in terms of $x_0$) and the distant from the origin to the vertex (something in terms of $x_0$)"?

I used $$\sin(x_0+iy) = \sin(x_0) \cosh(y) +i \cos(x_0) \sinh(y)$$ and $$ \sin(x+iy_0) = \sin(x) \cosh(y_0) + i \cos(x) \sinh(y_0)$$, but I don't know how to go beyond that to obtain a general formula for the mapping under $w=sin(z)$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the addition formula for the sine function?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I did, but I still don't understand how to derive a general formula for mapping under sin(z).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you explain what you did, how far you got, and where you're stuck in the body of your question.  You'll find that questions that say, "Here's a problem I can't solve; please do it for me," usually don't attract much of a response.  Please be sure to respond by **editing the question body.** Many people browsing questions will vote to close without looking at the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w = u + iv = \sin(x)\cosh(y) + i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$

For $y = y_0$ we have the parametrization

\begin{align}
u(x) &= a\sin(x) \\
v(x) &= b\cos(x)
\end{align}

where $a=\cosh(y_0)$ and $b=\sinh(y_0)$. This represents a horizontal ellipse with major and minor axes $a$ and $b$, respectively, since $\frac{u^2}{a^2}+\frac{v^2}{b^2}=1$. All ellipses have the focus $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=1$

Similarly, for $x=x_0$ we have the paremetrization

\begin{align}
u(y) &= a\cosh(y) \\
v(y) &= b\sinh(y)
\end{align}

where $a = \sin(x_0)$ and $b = \cos(x_0)$. This represents a hyperbola with major axis $a$, since $\frac{u^2}{a^2} - \frac{v^2}{b^2}=1$. The focus of every hyperbola is also $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this
[image: A]
[LINK](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/visualizations/7/)

Or this
[image: B]
[LINK](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcSin/visualizations/7/)

Probably the second one, with ellipses and hyperbolas.